# Call JSP and return data from Servlet upon receiving parameters

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am calling a JSP page in Jquery as

```
                onExpandRow: function(index,row){                    
                    height:160,  
                    border:true,  
                    cache:true,                          
                    href:'service.jsp?empNo='+empNo,
```

and in service.jsp I would like to pass the parameter to a servlet and return data in JSON.

JSP code snippet

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ url: "service.jsp",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(){
           $.get('myservlet?empNo=<%=request.getParameter("empNo")%>',
        function(data) {
```

For some reason this is not working, however if I am directly calling service.jsp?empNp=JAMES, then it works as I expect.

How and what is the best way to get values from servlet when I am calling service.jsp when I am clicking a row in Jquery? Ideally I would like to call service.jsp, as soon as service.jsp is called, would like to invoke servlet and return data and display the results.

Any help is highly appreciable.

Comment: in the jsp code snippet, why are you calling an ajax to the same page, and not directly calling myservlet ?

Comment: @DanyY The reason why I am calling the same page is to submit when I am calling jsp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understood correctly, but to answer your last question .
Here is my though :

Step 1 : in JSP you store the value of the parameter in a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="empNo" value="<%=request.getParameter("empNo")%>" />
```

Step 2 : You make an ajax call to myservlet on document.ready :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ url: "myservlet",
        data : {empNo : $('#empNo')}
        success: function(data){
//handle the result returned in data          
        }
       }
   }
```

Comment: Dany When I am calling `service.jsp` when I am expanding a row, call is not going to servlet. How can I call the servlet when call is being made to `service.jsp`?

Comment: It might be that document.ready is not beign called if you're not loading a new page.I'm thinking of smthg, why don't you call myservlet on the action to expand the row, and on success you open service.jsp.

Comment: Dany, issue has been resolved, there was a problem in my code which stopped calling `$(document).ready(function(){`. Thanks.